# userfrosting post json with csrf

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, csrf, userfrosting

I am porting a web application to userfrosting I need to post a JSON data object.  I am struggling with the csrf token.

The following code works fine with CSRF in userfrosting

```
    var postdata = {
      field1: 1,
      filed2: "data",
      csrf_token: $("meta[name=csrf_token]").attr("content")
    };

    $.ajax( { type: "POST", url: url, data: postdata, dataType: "json",
      success: ...,
      error: ...
    });
```

However, I need to post data as JSON and would like to use the following

```
    var postdata = {
      field1: 1,
      filed2: "data",
    };

    $.ajax( { type: "POST", url: url,
              data: JSON.stringify( postdata ), dataType: "json",
              contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      success: ...,
      error: ...
    });
```

How would I go about to add the csrf_token to get this working in userfrosting?

Comment: Does it not work when you include it in your `postdata` object, as you do in the first working example?

Comment: Thanks.  Yes, I did try to add the token in my JSON data without success.  It seems like userfrosting framework will not get the token from JSON post.  This could be a limitation in userfrosting.  If I do not find an alternative solution I will have to update my slim-hooks and parse the posts differently.  I was hoping that I would not need to.  Of course there is always an alternative (bad) option to remove the CSRF check.

Comment: Can you use your browser's console tools to inspect the request, and show us the data that is actually being submitted in the `POST`?